# Sorting a list key parameter

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.4

I have a problem on sorting a list, my goal is I'm trying to write a function that will sort a list of files based on their extension. For example given;

```
["a.c","a.py","b.py","bar.txt","foo.txt","x.c"]
```

desired output is;

```
["a.c","x.c","a.py","b.py","bar.txt","foo.txt"]
```

I fail when I tried to make a `key` parameter, I can't creating the algorithm. I tried to `split()` every file first, like;

```
def sort_file(lst):
    second_list = []
    for x in lst:
        t = x.split(".")
        second_list.append(t[1])
    second_list.sort()
```

But I just don't know what to do now, how can I make this sorted `second_list` as a `key` parameter then I can sort files based on their extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I fail when I tried to make a key parameter

`key` argument takes a function (callable, rather), that returns the object to compare against when given the list item as input. In your case, the `x.split(".")[1]` is the object to compare against. Take a look at [Python's wiki entry for sorting in this fashion](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions)

Something like the below should work for you.

```
>>> a = ["a.c","a.py","b.py","bar.txt","foo.txt","x.c"]
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: x.rsplit(".", 1)[1])
['a.c', 'x.c', 'a.py', 'b.py', 'bar.txt', 'foo.txt']
```

As @TanveerAlam says, using [`rsplit(..)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) is better because you'd want the split to be done from right.

Comment: `sorted(data, key=lambda x:x.rsplit('.', 1)[-1])` because file name may contain multiple `.` dots. Plus `rsplit` would be more efficient I think

Comment: @TanveerAlam What is `rsplit`  ? First time I heard

Comment: @TanveerAlam Good suggestion! I'll update my answer.

Comment: Why `r.split(,1)` ? What is the functionality of `1` there? Is that `max` value?

Comment: @sakirecayyok Read the documentation I linked in my answer. Yes, it is the maximum number of splits to be done.